# Laravel Form Class Submit Value as Part of Array

Tags: laravel-4

When using the Form helper class with Laravel / Blade, is there a way to format the $name value such that when the data is retrieved, it is organized as an array?

For example, in the view file, I want do something like:

```
{{ Form::input('params.sitename') }}
{{ Form::input('params.siteurl') }}
```

And then in the controller, when I call:

```
$data = Input::get('params');
```

$data will return:

```
array(
  'params' => array(
    'sitename' => 'data input from user',
    'siteurl' => 'more data input from user',
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good ol' php way:

```
{{ Form::input('params[sitename]') }}
{{ Form::input('params[siteurl]') }}

Input::get('params');
// array(
//    'sitename' => 'value-1',
//    'second'   => 'value-2'
// )
```